# TortoiseHg: No visual diff tools were detected (Mac)

Tags: macos, tortoisehg, meld

I installed `meld` in my Mac and i want to use this as a visual diff tool in TortoiseHg. (Note that I am using a Mac. )

I have the following configuration in my `.hgrc` file. But when I double clicked on a file, I got this "No visual diff tools were detected". Am I missing something in the file ?

This is getting a little bit frustrating because I have spent hours on this and still wasn't able to get a solution. Need some help here please .

```
[ui]
merge = /opt/local/bin/meld

[tortoisehg]
vdiff = /opt/local/bin/meld
```

Comment: for anyone still passing by here, there's a typo in OP `.hgrc` file: it's `merge`, without `d`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with `kdiff3` on osx, but I'm sure this solution works for `meld` as well. What worked was to enable the `extdiff` extension in mercurial, then define `kdiff3` as an `extdiff` command and use that in the `[tortoisehg]` section.

This is my `.hgrc` file with these changes made:

```
[extensions]
extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.kiddf3 = /usr/local/bin/kdiff3

[tortoisehg]
vdiff = kdiff3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have TortoiseHg locally installed in my home directory (since Ubuntu PPA was abandoned). My .hgrc starts with following line:

```
%include PATH_TO_THG_REPO/contrib/mergetools.rc
```

This file contains description of various merge and diff tools. Without it TortoiseHg doesn't detect any.

Once path to this file changed (when I copied .hgrc to another machine) and I got the same error message.

P.S.
Don't forget to replace PATH_TO_THG with your specific path.